# How to split a line into individual elements if one of the elements has a comma in it

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to parse a csv file into individual elements using .strip and .split

```
for line in infile:
    line = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
    id = int(line[0])
    name = str(line[1])
    average_user_rating = float(line[2])
    user_rating_count = int(line[3])
    developer = str(line[4])
    size = int(line[5])
```

But I don't think the .split(',') works for my file because there are commas in the name string.

```
289382458,Chess Game,3,504,Memention Holding AB,444163
290493286,Catcha Mouse,3.5,95971,"Meme, Inc",26820692
290614255,"Cool Sudoku, Jigsaw, Killer",3.5,357,Splash Software Ltd.,52236288
```

"Cool Sudoku, Jigsaw, Killer".
If I do .split(",") my line[2] would be ' Jigsaw' instead of 3.5.
May I know are there any other way to parse these elements?

Comment: Use the `csv` module, don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: [Please don't upload screenshots of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead use a code-block to format the text correctly. I've replaced your image with OCR text

Comment: Yes it does answer my question